# command line parameter to .command files

Tags: macos, terminal, command

How to pass arguments and process for .command files in mac?
I am using below in windows for batch files

```
cmd /c start F:\\startDriver.bat username
```

In bat file

```
@fake-command /u %1
```

%1 will hold username

How to do the same for .command file in mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmm, not sure what your real question is, but here you go...

Save this on your Desktop as `script1`

```
#!/bin/bash
~/Desktop/script2 xyz
```

Save this on your Desktop as `script2`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Parameter was $1
echo $LOGNAME
echo Press any key...
read -n 1
```

Now go to Terminal and make both executable

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/script*
```

Now you can double-click `script1` and it will run `script2` and show your username and the parameter it received from `script1`.